# Sort a find command by date

Tags: linux, bash, find, ls

I have a script:

```
newerthan="2016-02-08"
olderthan="2016-04-29"
find / -type f -name "*" -newermt "$newerthan" ! -newermt "$olderthan" -ls
```

This list files:

```
16481    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root         4096 Mar 16 11:41 /sys/module/sunrpc/srcversion
 16482    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root         4096 Mar 13 04:42 /sys/module/sunrpc/initstate
 16483    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root         4096 Mar 16 11:41 /sys/module/sunrpc/refcnt
 16485    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root         4096 Mar 17 11:41 /sys/module/sunrpc/sections/.note.gnu.build-id
 16486    0 -r--r--r--   1 root     root         4096 Mar 12 11:41 /sys/module/sunrpc/sections/.text
```

Is it possible to sort by date, the result ?

Comment: Try this: [How can I use `find` and sort the results by mtime?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29899/how-can-i-use-find-and-sort-the-results-by-mtime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print the filenames along with the date in sorted order:

```
find / -type f -name "*" -newermt "$newerthan" ! -newermt "$olderthan" -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort
```

If you want to print only the filenames in sorted order:

```
find / -type f -name "*" -newermt "$newerthan" ! -newermt "$olderthan" -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: If you want to reverse the order: use `sort -r` instead of `sort`.

Comment: macOS users will need `brew install findutils` and to replace `find` with `gfind`, as Apple's version of find doesn't support -printf.

Answer (score 1):

This returns a date sorted, timestamp restricted, list showing filenames

```
find / -type f -name "*" -newermt "$newerthan" ! -newermt "$olderthan"  -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -k 1 -n | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
```

If you need those other columns, you can alter the printf and sort parameters to show more columns and sort by position instead of by column